# Are the crystals on the hollow planet kyber crystals?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In season 6 episode 12, Yoda visits a hollow planet that is the origin of

> midi-chlorians.

Near the fissure where he goes in to the planet, there are crystals.  Since this is a planet that is strong in the Force, I was wondering if those were kyber crystals.

Comment: For the spoilers you type '>!' in front of your text, without the ' and it will make the spoilers box. Same as the quote with a ! added. Also, putting a whole question in spoilers is quite counterproductive, so i have only put in spoiler the important information.

Comment: Considering this episode aired over 4 years ago, is the spoiler really necessary at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those crystals are most likely kyber crystals. Yoda says that the planet is strong with the Force and he feels, and sees, the strong amount of life emanating from inside the planet. Kyber crystals resonate with the Force, and there is a lot of Force to resonate with at this planet.

Also kyber crystals are composed of both inorganic and organic material. Since there is a vast amount of organic material inside the planet, its not too far fetched that some of the organic matter helps to make the crystals.

One more note that reinforces that they are kyber crystals is that fact that the light that glows within each crystal fade in and out. Since the glow isn't from an outside light source its possibly a way to show their almost sentience, and them reacting to the Force emanating from inside the planet.

Answer (score -1):

they probably were, though since its a hard to find planet and force users usually only can find it and its strong in the force its hard to explain i'm watching it again right here and they are crystals i believe highly probable that they are cyber crystals hope that helps sorry if it doesn't